# Issue when removing the supportV4 library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

My app minimum version is 10
and till now i am using the support library for fragments

Now i want to add the flip animation for few fragment transition
So as per the android guide we need to use the animator for that 
and it has support from the api level 11 which is no issue for me.

but also need to use the `getFragmentManager` instead `getSupportFragmentManager`

So i removed the support library changed my minimum version 10 to 11 errors are coming

because in my app i have `FragmentTabhost` and `getChildFragmentManager()`.
`FragmentTabHost` only available on support library and to set `FragmentManager` using the `getChildFragmentManager` it wont allow me to do that because it requires api level 17

any help appreciated.
Let me know if you need more details

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not understand that your goal is to support API version 11 and above. Please state it more clearly after the first sentence,.

Comment: I think it would be better if you posted sample code, the important related ones. You may post code on Github and provide the link. At this point, I think it's easiest to give you sample project for Animation. Are you only interested in Flip Animation?

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Yes i am looking for the flip animation but needs it with support library and if i remove the support library it will create more problems as i told FragmentTabHost and getChildFragmentManager and other sttuf

Comment: seriously if google provides the fragments from the api 11 everthing related to fragment must work from 11 but like FragmentTabHost must have to use the support.v4.Fragment and also same for the getChildFragmentManager

Comment: i have created flip animation for fragment transition with this lib 'com.github.kedzie.supportanimator:support-v4-animator:19.0.0' but here problem is i can not update the support library

Comment: i have done flip with the following library with support also but this is not the solution because needs to update the support library also as we progress

Answer (score 5):

use android.support.v4.fragment instead of android.app Fragment in your project

and you can use following snippet for animation while adding/replacing fragment

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
.replace(R.id.fragment, new FragmenntTwo())
.commit();
```

where FragemntTwo() is the fragment you are inflating.Here you can use your custome animation as well by replacing setTransition(..) with setCustomAnimations(..)

Comment: Then please suggest how can i do the flip animation on fragment transition

Answer (score 4):

I think coding Animation for API level 10 and below is challenging, and rather obsolete. I can give one suggestion, read web page @ [NineOldAndroids from the active developer Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids). It supports Android 1.0 and up, though deprecated with new Android libraries. So one lesson is that it would be easier for you to create a new project, basically start over instead of converting code.

Even if you do use existing animation like [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html), the API level is 11 and up. You're hitting that boundary between level 10 and 11 for animation.

Good luck and keep us posted.

Comment: Yes i have created new app with min version 11 now i have add the flip animation with the new animation api using animator now i want to add the bottom tabs on the app it requires `FragmentTabHost` that only available in the support library i have done the workaround for that also directly copied the `FragmentTabHost` class to app but now i have to use the getChildFragmentManager as it requires that is have from api 17 and if i want to make it support from the 11 then force fully need to use the support library and if use support i cant do flip animation that makes me down again

Answer (score 3):

Custom animation works with Support Fragment manager too. you will be able to use the support fragment manager and still animate it.

Comment: if you use the Support Fragments it requires the animation resource from the anim folder only 
And we need to use the animator for flip so need to create the animator folder

Answer (score 2):

For `FragmentTabhost` ,I used to build a program with `app.Fragment`,but suddenly my PM told me he want to use `ViewPager` +`Fragment`. What i did was copy the `FragmentPagerAdapter.class` from v4.jar and replace all these `v4.Fragment` with `app.Fragment`.I think this may help you.
And for `getChildFragmentManager()`, `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` may help you.

Comment: but @SuppressLint("NewApi") will only hide the error but it wont work lower api version then 17 let me correct if i was wrong